# how to return a validation property on a hapi reply like the way Joi library does it

Tags: hapi.js, joi

I have my own custom validation on a property and I'd like to return a 400 response that is similar to the the JOI.validation that is returned on the other fields.  This means that in addition to the error and message I'd like to return a validation property as well - so that the client can know which field to highlight.

So, instead of this

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "phone validation error: invalid phone number"
}
```

I'd like to reply with this

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
     "error": "Bad Request",
     "message": "phone validation error: invalid phone number"
     "validation": {
     "source": "payload",
      "keys": [
            "phone"
      ]

}
```

How do I add the validation the the hapi reply?

I've been doing this - which has not been working

```
        e.validation =
        {
            source: "payload",
            keys: [
                "phone"
            ]
        }
        reply(Boom.badRequest(e));
```

I'm also assuming that I cannot have custom validators for Joi, otherwise I would have just extended Joi.  But, is there a Joi validation error type or object I can use in the reply to get Joi like object structure in my response.

BTW, my phone validation is not a simple regex and has special cases so I cannot use the Joi built in regex validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the object returned by boom.badRequest('some message'), you'll get:

```
{ data: null,
  isBoom: true,
  isServer: false,
  output:
   { statusCode: 400,
     payload:
      { statusCode: 400,
        error: 'Bad Request',
        message: 'some message' },
     headers: {} },
  reformat: [Function] }
```

So you actually need to do something like

```
var errObj = Boom.badRequest(e);
errObj.output.payload.validation =
{
  source: "payload",
  keys: [
    "phone"
  ]
}
reply(errObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var errObj = Boom.badRequest(e);
errObj.validation =
    {
        source: "payload",
        keys: [
            "phone"
        ]
    }
reply(errObj);
```

Comment: that didn't work - hapi seems to trip out the validation property on the result if I populate it manually

Comment: Perhaps you should raise an issue on GitHub.